How can I check nulls in Logstash pipeline in filter plugin?
I have a source which sends data to my Logstash pipeline via Logstash http plugin.
The data model which is sent like:
{
  "myArray": [
    {
      "myGrocery": {
        "myId": "aString",
        "apple": "aString",
        "banana": aNumber,
        "vegetable": {
          "garlic": "aString",
          "onion": "aString",
          "mushroom": "aString",    
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

My filter plugin in Logstash:
filter {

    split {
        field => "myArray"
        add_field => {
            "my_id" => "%{[myArray][myGrocery][myId]}"
            "apple" => "%{[myArray][myGrocery][apple]}"
            "banana" => "%{[myArray][myGrocery][banana]}"           
            "vegetable" => "%{[myArray][myGrocery][vegetable]}"
        }
        remove_field => "myArray"
    }

    json {
        source => "[vegetable]"
        target => "[vegetable]"
    }

    mutate {
        rename => { "[vegetable][garlic]" => "[vegetable][myNewGarlic]" }
        rename => { "[vegetable][onion]" => "[vegetable][myNewOnion]" }
        rename => { "[vegetable][mushroom]" => "[vegetable][myNewMushroom]" }
    }

    mutate {
        remove_field => [ "host", "headers", "@version", "url", "event", "user_agent", "http" ]
    }

}


Everything is working fine but I want to display "null" if the banana is sent as null and save it as a log message "banana is null" but I do not want to drop the whole information. The result should be like:
"myId": "aString",
"apple": "aString",
"banana": "null",
"myNewGarlic" : "aString",
"myNewOnion": "aString",
"myNewMushroom": "aString",

Is it possible to do this? And how?

I solved it finally. The problem was the place of myArray. I removed it after splitting banana property.
    split {
        field => "myArray"
        add_field => {
            "my_id" => "%{[myArray][myGrocery][myId]}"
            "apple" => "%{[myArray][myGrocery][apple]}"              
            "vegetable" => "%{[myArray][myGrocery][vegetable]}"
        }
    }


    if [myArray][myGrocery][banana] {
        mutate {           
            add_field => {
            "my_banana" => "%{[myArray][myGrocery][banana]}"
            }
        }
    } else {
        mutate {            
            add_tag => [ "my_banana is null" ]
        }
    }

    mutate {       
        remove_field => "myArray"
    }

This added a tags property in ELS showing "my_banana is null" if my_banana null is.
In these cases, it "banana" returns null
null
"false"
""
false
if there is no field at all


You can use logstash if condition to check if the banana field has some value. If not you can use mutate filter to add/edit/update the field value.
input {}
filter {
  if ! [banana]  {
    mutate { update => { "banana" => "null" } }
    mutate { add_tag => "banana is null" }
    }
  }
output {}

Note: You can also check null value processor in Elasticsearch.

Thanks but since it is a numeric value and I have to split it in split plugin it gives this error: "exception=>LogStash::Json::ParserError"

Before the split you can check whether if that field has value.
if ![myArray][myGrocery][banana] if not add "null" before the split.

I also tried it but it throws exception. I think this is because my field has a type of byte. "caused_by"=>{"type"=>"number_format_exception", "reason"=>"For input string: "%{[myArray][myGrocery][banana]}""}   I tried instead of "null" used 99 or "99" still the same.

I don't think it's related to the field type because there is no field type logic in Logstash. If you got exception about the field value, it can be because of index mapping in Elasticsearch. But the error you shared looks Logstash logs. Can you try with output => stdout  and share the full error with me?
